# Extracting from a line in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to group my data by url. My data is currently stored in one long line. E.g.:
{"mobile","country:US","url:1234.com","newuser:y"} etc.

Here is what I have so far:

```
RAW = LOAD '/data/events/raw/2014-08-21/' as (line:chararray);
A = FILTER RAW BY (INDEXOF(line,'mobile') != -1)
B = LIMIT A 800;
URL = GROUP B BY (INDEXOF(line, 'url'));
STORE URL INTO '/user/hadoopuser/RS_traffic.txt';
```

How do I go about extracting the URL from the string in order to group by it? Can I use regex?

Comment: Your input looks like json you can try or load using JsonStorage http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/func.html#jsonloadstore

Comment: this is not a valid JSON

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `REGEX_EXTRACT()` function:

[REGEX_EXTRACT Javadoc](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/REGEX_EXTRACT.html)

```
RAW = LOAD '/data/events/*' AS (line:chararray);
C = FOREACH RAW GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(value, '<your_pattern>', 1) AS url:chararray;
A = FILTER RAW BY (INDEXOF(line,'mobile') != -1)
URL = GROUP C BY url;
....
STORE URL INTO '/user/hadoopuser/RS_traffic.txt';
```